# How can I make php action stay on this page until I exit with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My HTML page is a form where I type in the upper bound for the random number generator and on submit, use AJAX to submit the form parameter as a HTTP request to a PHP script and then it writes the random number generated by the php to an empty div but when I hit submit, the number is there for only a split second until it goes away.

How can I edit my JQuery to get the random number to stay in the div until I either resubmit or leave the page?

In the code: The #x ID is the general form, the #y ID is the input where the upper bound is put and the #random ID is the div where the random number goes.

```
$('#x').on('submit', function() {
  $('#random').load('random.php', $('#y').serialize());
});
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` should do the trick. It prevents the form submit from re-loading the page. You must add the `event` parameter to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#x').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#random').load('random.php', $('#y').serialize());
  // or use:
  // return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I hit submit, the number is there for only a split second until it goes away.

It's not exactly what happens: it does NOT go away. At the opposite, it is overwritten (in fact, like the whole page), because when you submit... then you submit!
(so because you didn't set a different `action` attribute to your `<form>`, the current page is loaded again)

In other words the important thing is that *you don't want the form to be submitted*, but only the `submit` event to be catched to do your job.

So the solution is simply to make the `submit` event to be stopped as soon you did the `load()`:

```
$('#x').on('submit', function() {
  $('#random').load('random.php', $('#y').serialize());
  return false; // <-- prevent to execute the real submit action
});
```